# Can I use creationRequestForAssetFromVideo for remote URL?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Can I use `creationRequestForAssetFromVideo` to download and copy a video on remote server to my user's photo album instead of using URLSession first and then downloading and copying the video?

Answer (score 1):

According to document from Apple (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetchangerequest/1624057-creationrequestforassetfromvideo), this function "creationRequestForAssetFromVideo" is for parameter of file URL, which is not for remote URL. So you have to download the file by URLSession first.